# How to get back to a git branch after a git revert

Tags: git

So, I ended up having to change the whole directory tree of my project because of a fundamental problem with my code - or so I thought.  So I made a commit before the big changes, then I realized after making the changes that I did not need to.  So I performed

```
git checkout ##SHA##
```

I was able to make the whole project working the way it should, but now I have a different problem.  I am no longer checked-out in the branch I was working in.  How do I keep the code I have now and get back to working within the branch?

```
git branch -a
```

says that I am in

```
* (no branch)
```

Anyone know what I can do without just making a new branch and deleting the old one?

Comment: Tried `git checkout master`? Or the name of your branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never do `git checkout <hash>`. It is meant to temporarily examine a commit (and hence the no branch that you see). What you wanted to do was, while in the branch, `git reset --hard <hash>` ( remove the --hard if you have changes you need in the working directory.)

To recover:

```
git checkout the_branch
git reset --hard <hash>
```

Note that the `<hash>` above is going to be the same one that you used with `git checkout` while trying to "revert" the changes.

Comment: Great Answer!  Very informative... thank you for telling us what `git checkout <hash>` is really for!

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to make a few edits after I complete that and then make a commit?  I know the current `<hash>` is good... Why should I not just `git checkout my_branch` and then `git merge <hash of the current commit that I know works>`?  Or would I be forced to make a new branch so that I can commit it and then merge that new branch it into the saved commit before the experiment?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me recover my headless commits from being gc'ed and reset the topic branch on them.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout back to your branch, then merge the changes you made on the headless branch:

```
git checkout my_branch
git merge ##SHA##
```

You should then have branch `my_branch` at the latest commit you've made.

Comment: I really like this answer because it solves the problem the fastest - so everyone please note that this is really the best answer in direct answer to my question.  However @carleeto has an educational point which I believe wins the "Answer" because I would like for future visitors to have the benefit of understanding -carleeto's educational point.

Comment: **This really is the fastest and most direct way to solve this problem**

Comment: So... right now I have a detached head state right?  does that state have a ##SHA##?? (<hash>) that I can reference after checking out the older, but "correct branch"?  Or will the process of checking out that branch destroy that code with no way to reference it?

Comment: First, make sure to commit your changes to the detached head. Then use `git log` and copy the top commit hash, checkout the branch and merge with said hash.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a branch: `git branch -b branch_for_new_code`
2. Add and commit your changes.
3. Checkout the branch you want to get back to: `git checkout branch_i_was_on`
4. Merge the new branch with the old: `git merge branch_for_new_code`
5. Delete the new branch once it has been merged.

For the future, remember a simple rule of thumb: When you're doing something you're not sure about, make a branch first. Finally, only checkout branch names unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: This is a great point.  Thank you for helping me understand git practices better for the future!  Cheers mate, -J.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you are where you want the branch to be, you can:

```
git branch -D my_branch
git checkout -b my_branch
```

This deletes the old branch pointer, and creates a new one pointing to your current HEAD.